# What are the security implications of using local-link XMPP on an untrusted network?

Tags: network, xmpp

I'd like to setup [XMPP local-link](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html) messaging (Bonjour) on my laptop for use at home. However, I'm concerned about ensuring this is not leaking any information when I connect to an untrusted network.

When this is enabled what information can it expose to the network?

Is there a way on Debian I can ensure this is only enabled when I am connected to a trusted network?